# Given that I know the initial speed, elevation and target location of a projectile, how do I find the launch angle?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, vectors, projectile

I have a system where I know how far away a target is, the relative elevation and an initial launch speed with gravity, no drag. What I need to figure out is what angle (relative to the floor plane) I need to launch the projectile at initially to hit this target. This didn't seem particularly complicated for a relative elevation of $0$, but this isn't a restriction I can safely add

To be clear this is in the context of a game, essentially you aim a target and launch a projectile at it. Relative elevation can vary but is always known

I have attempted to solve this already, but I think I made things only more confusing and ended up with an equation I couldn't solve, so
I'm at a point of 4 possibilities:

1. I'm on completely the wrong track
2. I messed something up (pretty likely)
3. There's a rule I don't know that would help me nail this down
4. It's actually not possible (seems really unlikely given how easy it is to find the target based on initial launch angle and elevation, but I don't know for sure)

To begin with, I have a few basic values, everything is in $units$ rather than meters since they're generic here (I'm explicitly writing this out because I find it helpful as someone who doesn't use symbolic math like this a lot, my background is programming)

$V = initial\ velocity\ (u/s)$

$g = gravity\ (u/s^2)$

$d = travel\ (u)$

$t = time\ (s)$

travel, gravity and initial velocity are all known constants, $t$ increases linearly over time

[image]

I broke things down into the two motions - vertical motion and horizontal motion (let's assume $x$ is horizontal motion, and $y$ is vertical motion, to keep things confusing $-y$ is up), and wrote out the equations representing each:

$
d_x = V\cos(\theta)t
$

$
d_y = (V\sin(\theta) + gt)t
$

With $\theta$ representing the initial launch angle
Based on this, I rearranged each one to solve for $t$, so I could make them equivalent.
Horizontal is easy:

$$\frac{d_x}{V\cos\theta} = t$$

Vertical is a couple of extra steps, expanded out:

$$
gt^2 + V\sin(\theta)t - d_y = 0
$$

Putting the values into the quadratic formula gives me this:

$$
t = \frac{-V\sin\theta\pm\sqrt{(V\sin\theta)^2 + 4gd_y}}{2g}
$$

So now I can set the two equations to equal each other and remove $t$ completely (since I don't really care about it)

$$
\frac{d_x}{V\cos\theta} = \frac{-V\sin\theta\pm\sqrt{(V\sin\theta)^2 + 4gd_y}}{2g}
$$

Quick rearrange:

$$
\frac{2gd_x}{V\cos\theta} + V\sin\theta = \pm\sqrt{(V\sin\theta)^2 + 4gd_y}
$$

Square both sides:
$$
\frac{4g^2d_x^2}{V^2\cos{^2}\theta} + \frac{4gd_xV\sin\theta}{V\cos\theta} + (V\sin\theta)^2 = (V\sin\theta)^2 + 4gd_y
$$

Cancel out those $(V\sin\theta)^2$ and shift to $= 0$, pretty sure I can remove the common $4g$'s as well
$$
\frac{gd_x^2}{V^2\cos{^2}\theta} + \frac{d_xV\sin\theta}{V\cos\theta} - d_y = 0
$$

Next I tried getting rid of those divisions by $V^2\cos{^2}\theta$ by multiplying each element by $\frac{V\cos\theta}{V\cos\theta}$ as needed, which should result in the much more simple looking
$$
gd_x^2 + d_xV^2\sin\theta\cos\theta - d_yV^2\cos{^2}\theta = 0
$$

Clean up and divide by $V^2$, and I get what looks like a simple quadratic (makes sense, since there should be up to 2 solutions)
$$
d_y\cos{^2}\theta - d_x\sin\theta\cos\theta - \frac{gd_x^2}{V^2} = 0
$$

...and that's as far as I got. I can't think of any way of getting any closer to $\theta$ from here while ever there's a $\sin\theta$ stuck to that $\cos\theta$ (the quadratic formula doesn't help me since I still end up with a $\cos\theta$ dependent on a $\sin\theta$). I think I need to find a way to have only 1 type of trigonometric function. It's pretty likely I'm missing something, I did try a website that solves math things to try this for $\theta$ but no dice. This makes me think an alternate approach is needed

It's quite probable I'm being a little verbose, but I figured if I post every step someone can clearly point out to me where I've messed this thing up

Other things I know:

- Range will be limited (probably based on $d_x$ for $\theta=45^o$) to prevent imaginary results
- I only really care about the solutions for $45^o\le\theta\le90^o$ since they result in the longest air time

Worst case I can probably make an approximation (using the power of trial-and-error), but the preference is accuracy based on these other values

Any help is hugely appreciated! I'm a little rusty on this particular area

Comment: So my issue's been solved (it was "I'm on completely the wrong track" after all, over-complicated things for myself and got myself in a stickier situation), but I have to ask - what's the reasoning for the downvote on the question? I'm not mad (which makes me sound mad lol) but I want to know what I could've done better? I tried searching, found nothing and I was clear (I think) with what I'd already tried. Or is it just my reward for being an idiot?

Comment: I didn’t downvote, but homework-like and check-my-work questions are off-topic, so that might be why you got downvoted.

Comment: *to keep things confusing −y is up* Why would you do that? Didn’t that cause your mistake?

Comment: Huh, interesting. I'd seen similar questions here already (though they didn't answer my question) so I assumed itd be ok to ask. Guess I've got more to learn

Comment: -y makes sense in context (I included the detail in case it was relevant) but it wasn't the cause of my mistake, since the solution doesn't care what sign Up has as long as I'm consistent with gravity and displacement etc, my issue was down to A) forgetting one of the fundamental equations of motion, B) overcomplicating things for no good reason and C) not knowing an important relationship between some trig functions (cos, sec and tan specifically) that would've enabled me to solve this thing way more easily

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not have to work so hard. You already have the correct time
$$\tag1t=\frac{d_x}{V\cos\vartheta}$$
The old kinematics equation says
$$\tag2s=ut+\frac12at^2\qquad\implies\qquad-d_y=Vt\sin\vartheta-\frac12gt^2$$
$$\tag3-d_y=d_x\tan\vartheta-\frac12g\frac{d_x^2}{V^2}\sec^2\vartheta$$
$$\tag4\frac12g\left(\frac{d_x}V\right)^2\tan^2\vartheta-d_x\tan\vartheta+\frac12g\left(\frac{d_x}V\right)^2-d_y=0$$
$$\tag5\tan^2\vartheta-2\frac{V^2}{gd_x}\tan\vartheta+1-2\frac{V^2d_y}{gd_x^2}=0$$
which is a quadratic in $\tan\vartheta$ ready to be easily solved.

You have an equation that is very similar to the one I have. Comparing the two, it is clear you have some sign mistakes.

Comment: Thank you so much! I knew I needed to get to a tan somehow, and now that you've pointed out what I should've been doing it's so obvious, I've gone and over complicated things in my own head and tunnel vision'd too hard to see it. Huge, huge thank you

Comment: Ok I'm gonna be really annoying and thank you further because reading and working through this it's actually really clear I probably couldn't have worked this out on my own (and not just because I forgot how equations of motion work among other things), because I had a complete gap in my knowledge - I had no idea what a secant was or how it interacted with the other trig functions - so double thanks! I've been reading up so I can get a real understanding and I think it's going to be very useful to me - you've taught me a valuable thing